# Simple search form shows entries with closed status

Tags: search, status, simple-search

I use the following simple search tag:

```
{exp:search:simple_form channel="content|symposium|whos_who|nieuws" results="9" search_in="entries" where="all" result_page="zoeken/index" no_result_page="zoeken/no-result" status="not closed"}
```

But weirdly enough, it displays entries when the search is done which are closed. It doesn't matter what I put the status parameter on. How can this happen?

Comment: Have you tried proper case "Closed"? I haven't tried just yet but from memory the default statuses of Open and Closed are case sensative for some weird and strange reason...

Comment: Arvenzis, can you please edit your question and let us know the EE version you are using, and note that you are using EE Publisher module please? it's very relivent to the question. also, could you check you are not confusingthe output of the Publisher status as opposed tothe EE status (they are independant)

Answer (score 1):

Your question peaked my interest, so I put together a test on my sandbox. I admit this is an out of date EE2.8.1.

I tried out a number of variations however the one thing that springs out to me is that the "not" in status seems to cause unexpected results. For example I did a search with `status="not open"` and got no results (expecting 2), when I say "no results" I mean I got an error message about invalid action! Certainly not as expected.

I re-did the search with `status="closed"` and immediately got the 2 results I was execting.

So my conclusion is that the not part seems less than iron cast. through experimentation can I suggest you list the acceptible statuses in the status attribute, instead of "not" statuses?

If this works out for you, I'd perhaps pose it as a bug...

Comment: It does show only closed items when I say status="closed", but I'm trying to show the opened items. I've trying a lot of things, like: Open, open, opened, Opened, not closed, but it keeps showing the closed and the opened results.

It might be a bug indeed.

Comment: Are you absolutely, 100% sure all 4 of your channels have a Status Group applied in thier Group Preferences? This could cause issues as a channel with "none" set on Status Group in Group Preferences will allow admins to set a status in the CP, but may not be filterable! Can you double check your channel group preferences, also can you de-evolve your test to check one channel at a time? try `status="open"` and `status="closed"` for each channel and check each one works/fails. If we can narrow it down we can probably debug a bit more rather than a 1 line bug report...

Comment: A little more debugging help, the piece of code that applies the status filter is located here `/system/expressionengine//modules/search/mod.search.php Line : 664`. I  see it auto corrects Closed to closed and Open to open. I also see a strange comment on line 671 `// add exclusion for closed unless it was explicitly used`. This code definatly doesn't look strong, basically from waht I see the not clause may well be faulty!

Comment: Last thing I note is that if you JUST want open entries, drop the status attribute completely, as if there's no status attribute it automatically filters on `status='open'`. One last place to check, the `exp_channel_titles.status` column in your DB, are these set as expected??

Comment: if you wanted to see the query as its being built you can put `die($sql);` in the file around line 688 (after status calculation) or you could put it at line 1158 and you can copy the entire darned query into phpmyadmin/MySql and test it manually! Also, you haven't got entry date and/or expiration date issues have you? I notice you're not dealing with future entries so it'll apply an entry_date < now type query.

Comment: All channels are set on statuses in group preferences. Removing the whole status parameter doesn't work as well, that's what I had at first, because I know that ExpressionEngine should normally automatically only get the entries with open statusses. The database does show intries that contain status closed and open. Although I am using publisher and in the entry itself it says "Published", not "Open". When I use published in my status parameter, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Using the query that die($sql); returns shows this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT(exp_channel_titles.entry_id) FROM exp_channel_titles' at line 1

Comment: Ok, I'm afraid I don' know Publisher but that will definatly make a difference as it hooks status. I would recommend getting into Publishers documentation as this is very relivent. Also, try without Publisher, does the native channel entries tag work wirthout Publishers interference? Lastly the die statement should not cause an exception message that you state. it should echo out the string $sql and stop processing, I'd double check that if your so inclined :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a bug in the module Publisher. If anyone is experiencing the same problem, update Publisher and if that doesn't work, contact Boldminded.